# How does assert groupType != null contain 4 branches

Tags: code-coverage, assert, jacoco, eclemma

I need to test the following code.

```
public List<PatientGroup> findGroups(final String groupType) throws HwBaseAppException
{
    assert groupType != null;//4 branches here
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=persistence.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<PatientGroup> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PatientGroup.class);
    Root<PatientGroup> patientGroupRoot = query.from(PatientGroup.class);
    Predicate condition=criteriaBuilder.equal(patientGroupRoot.get(PatientGroup_.active), Boolean.TRUE);
    Join<PatientGroup, GroupSubType> groupSubTypeRoot = patientGroupRoot.join(PatientGroup_.groupSubType);
    Predicate condition1=criteriaBuilder.equal(groupSubTypeRoot.get(GroupSubType_.groupTypeCode), groupType);
    query.where(condition,condition1);
    query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(patientGroupRoot.get(PatientGroup_.name)));
    TypedQuery<PatientGroup> tq = persistence.createQuery(query);       
    List<PatientGroup> collections = tq.getResultList();
    return initializeGroupRelationships(collections);
}
```

In my test case i am passing both null and not null values which should cover both the branches however Code coverage says 1 of 4 branches missed.What are the other 2 branches?
Below are my test cases.

```
 @Test
    public void testFindGroups_1()
        throws HwBaseAppException
    {   
        Mockito.when(persistence.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        Mockito.when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PatientGroup.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        Mockito.when(criteriaQuery.from(PatientGroup.class)).thenReturn(patientGroupRoot);
        Mockito.when(patientGroupRoot.join(PatientGroup_.groupSubType)).thenReturn(groupSubTypeRoot);
        Mockito.when(persistence.createQuery(Mockito.any(CriteriaQuery.class))).thenReturn(tq);
        Mockito.when(tq.getResultList()).thenReturn(arrayList);
        Mockito.when(arrayList.iterator()).thenReturn(iterator);
        Mockito.when(iterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
        Mockito.when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(patientGroup);
        groupServiceDAOImpl.findGroups("groupType");    
    }
    @Test(expected=AssertionError.class)
    public void testFindGroups_2()
        throws HwBaseAppException
    {   
        groupServiceDAOImpl.findGroups(null);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclEmma Eclipse plugin provides coverage analysis using [JaCoCo library](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/), which in his turn analyzes bytecode. Let's take a simplified example:

```
class Example {
  void example(Object x) {
    assert x != null;
  }
}
```

And let's have a look on its bytecode:

```
javac Example.java
javap -v Example
```

Which looks like:

```
 0: getstatic     #2                  // Field $assertionsDisabled:Z
 3: ifne          18
 6: aload_1
 7: ifnonnull     18
10: new           #3                  // class java/lang/AssertionError
13: dup
14: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/AssertionError."<init>":()V
17: athrow
18: return
```

As you can see - there are actually 2 conditions:

1. assertions enabled (`ifne`)
2. `x` is not `null` (`ifnonnull`)

And so 4 possible variants.

Comment: can you please help on how i can get the left over branch for(assertions enabled (ifne)) covered , based on your input i have passed 0 as an argument but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @AviralSaxena see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable about how to enable/disable assertions in Java. Speaking about tests and code quality - in this particular case could be that there is no need to cover all branches.

Comment: @AviralSaxena btw don't forget to upvote and accept an answer, if it answers your questions. Thanks.